# should I use websockets or webRTC for 4player game

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket, webrtc

I am currently making a html5 game with node.js and socket.io.
The basics of the game are 4 people moving around as circles trying to hit eachother...

My question is should I use Websockets or WebRTC?
What is best for this kind of communication? peer to peer with 4 players or over a server?

Feel free to share your thoughts, I'm pretty new to this stuff..

Comment: The primary thing you want ask is: who owns the state and data? If state and data are stored on the clients and sent/received directly to and from each other, what happens if a client gets disconnected? Does part of the game go away? What if they cheat by mucking about with the data? Would you rather the server own the data (or at least validate it) for those reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebRTC can be used not only for streaming audio/video, but also for sending data. And P2P is useful when sending huge amount of data.

In your case the traffic is very small. And I see many advantages of using a server - synchronization, or in the future, features like authentication or history.

There is also the implementation part. With WebRTC you still need a signaling server. And websockets are much easier to implement, as you don't have the session negotiation part. Also the connection is faster.

Personally, in your case I would not bother with WebRTC.

*Later update:* There's also the problem of browser support: [websockets](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets) vs [WebRTC](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc), as @Myst mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I would also mention that WebRTC's browser support is currently limited. Websockets will work on a wider variety of browsers and clients.

Comment: If using the latest socket.io you can use socket.io p2p to have it set up webrtc data channels between clients without any additional overhead. http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-p2p/

Comment: thanks for the response, browser support is not that important as I'm doing this for a school assignment aimed on new technologies.
is it possible to use this p2p socket.io has in a 4player environment though, since it says a bidirectional events channel between two peer? think I will try it with the sockets first and see how things progress..

Comment: If you have web sockets, then that's your signaling server. ;)

Comment: websocket connections are no faster or slower than data channels, and data channels have lower latency between clients (see [NB update near bottom of this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18978966/edit).)

Comment: I didn't say that websocket connections are faster or slower, but the connection part, as WebRTC involves a session negotiation. Though if you use it only for data could be faster.
@Pieter-JanDeBruyne, if you're using this for a school assignment, browser support could not be relevant, but I guess development speed is. So from this point of view, I would go with websockets.

Comment: "Also the connection is faster" Got a source on that? I find it hard to believe TBH.

Comment: Is it possible in anyway to send WebRTC data through an authoritarian server? Because if not, using it for gaming would be pointless because of hackers, correct? Just curious ty

Comment: @NiCkNewman, what do you mean by pointless? Are you referring to the fact that any of the parties can tamper with the data flow? Yes, it's possible. 
And there's no way to route WebRTC traffic through a server. That will beat its purpose: p2p connectivity.

Comment: @Kevin, I don't have a reference for that. But from my experience, websockets are connecting instantly, while WebRTC session negotiation could take at least few seconds. Though I haven't tried connecting for data transfer only.

Comment: The only reason to prefere webrtc over websocket would be latency. p2p allows to minimize latencys.

Answer (score 5):

Use both.

WebRTC data channels are great for sending data with the lowest possible latency between clients, since the data does not go through a server.

From the game you describe, it sounds like low latency will be critical, so I would definitely look at using data channels to update opponents' positions as quickly as possible.

At the same time, I'd send data with web sockets to the server as well, as the keeper of truth in the game, to verify that no-one is cheating.

Fours player should not be a problem. Have each client open a peer connection to all the other clients, in a "mesh".